# Insert missing rows in a specific time series

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a specific time-series dataset which is as bellow.

```
0     2018-01-01 00:00:00+00:00  ...                             
1     2018-01-01 00:10:00+00:00  ...                              
2     2018-01-01 00:20:00+00:00  ...                             
3     2018-01-01 00:30:00+00:00  ...                             
4     2018-01-01 00:50:00+00:00  ...                            
5     2018-01-01 01:00:00+00:00  ...                              
6     2018-01-01 01:20:00+00:00  ...                             
7     2018-01-01 01:40:00+00:00  ...
.
.
.
```

However, there are some missing rows in the dataset.
I have searched how to insert rows for this specific dataset and did not find any useful help. In this dataset, we have to add rows that every 10 minutes have an entry and other columns should have Nan values.

any idea?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. It would be great if you could show some code of your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `DatetimeIndex` first and call [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```
print (df)
                    date_col  value
0  2018-01-01 00:00:00+00:00      4
1  2018-01-01 00:10:00+00:00      9
2  2018-01-01 00:20:00+00:00      1
3  2018-01-01 00:30:00+00:00      6
4  2018-01-01 00:50:00+00:00      3
5  2018-01-01 01:00:00+00:00      4
6  2018-01-01 01:20:00+00:00      5
7  2018-01-01 01:40:00+00:00      0

#if necessary
df['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'])

df = df.set_index('date_col').asfreq('10Min')
print (df)
                           value
date_col                        
2018-01-01 00:00:00+00:00    4.0
2018-01-01 00:10:00+00:00    9.0
2018-01-01 00:20:00+00:00    1.0
2018-01-01 00:30:00+00:00    6.0
2018-01-01 00:40:00+00:00    NaN
2018-01-01 00:50:00+00:00    3.0
2018-01-01 01:00:00+00:00    4.0
2018-01-01 01:10:00+00:00    NaN
2018-01-01 01:20:00+00:00    5.0
2018-01-01 01:30:00+00:00    NaN
2018-01-01 01:40:00+00:00    0.0
```